# When emitting particles in a volume, how do I prevent particles from appearing inside other objects within that volume?

Tags: particles

I have a scene where I emit particles as debris over a volume in the scene. Within that volume I have other objects with colliders. A few particles will appear inside the objects and fly off of them at high speed.

How do I prevent these particles from appearing inside these other objects?

My first thought was to have particles kill on collision during the first frame or two, however I am not sure how to have the setting change on a frame to frame basis.

Answer (score 0):

I now this is a very old question, but I was wondering the same, found this unanswered and later figured out a solution (which probably wouldn't work 8 years ago) - You can built a low poly colliders around your objects and boolean difference the objects from the emitter.